# izpack installer -options-auto

Tags: izpack

I need to run my installer from console with `java -jar myinstaller.jar` and  I need to set all properties automatically. I read the articles and figured out the way to do this.

Here is the [article](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Advanced+Features).

We can do this with `java -jar myinstaller.jar -options-auto <propfile>`  but I could not find the xml format which izpack can parse it. I have searched the source codes but there were no success.

Is there anyone knows that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save a recorded xml file of your input at the Finishpanel during a non-console execution. This should show you the format.

Comment: Does FinishPanel need some argument or writing the <panel  classname="FinishPanel" /> is enough?

Comment: <panel classname="FinishPanel" /> is enough.